# Spinnaker: Best way to consume an artifact inside a webhook stage's payload?

Tags: spinnaker

All,

I have a situation where I want to use an bitbucket/file artifact (as a base64 string) inside a webhook stage in Spinnaker. The idea is to read the Expected Artifact from the pipeline execution and inject it.

However, I can't find an elegant way of doing it? So far I've written a webhook that will take the reference of an artifact (`${trigger.resolvedExpectedArtifacts[3].boundArtifact.reference}`) to call and retrieve the actual artifact. Then inside the *second* web hook I have this: `${ #stage('Retrieve (swagger)')['context']['webhook']['body'] }`

Is there no other way to 'resolve' the artifact and pass it to my stage without doing this?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use artifact itself you will need additional stage to retrieve it. So the simple case is to use webhook for it. But such manipulations look like micromanagement in Spinnaker. You can avoid it by delegating some work related to extracting artifact and doing come actions with to:

- [Jenkins Job](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#jenkins) or another CI system
- [Kubernetes Job](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/kubernetes-v2/run-job-manifest/)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. The expected artifact is NOT a base64 artifact at the start of the pipeline. It's a bitbucket/file artifact, and that is the problem...these artifacts aren't retrieved at the start of the pipeline, so the reference value is purely the URL to the artifact itself, e.g. reference: https://bitbucket/myproject/path/to/file.json. At the moment I'm using the webhook stage to then go and retrieve it and then reference it via the ${#stage} expression in the next stage. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks! I thought so but just wanted to confirm this.